# What's maximum length allowed for string type User profile property in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-property

[image: String Type User profile property]
Default length for string type property is 25. 
Let me know maximum length allowed for it's value.

Answer (score 7):

In SharePoint Online you are currently allowed to have as many as 3600 characters in a User Profile Property string (Single Value). I tried to add 10’000, and got a helpful error message:

[image]

On SharePoint Server 2010 the max value is 1999, and on SharePoint Server 2013 the max value is the same as in SharePoint Online; 3600.

Comment: How about string(multivalue)?

Comment: Can you link to a reference for this, @benny-skogberg?

Comment: Just tested this, the limit of 3600 characters is still correct.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint online with user profile property of String(Multivalued), even after selecting maximum length of 3600, a single value has hard limit on 255 characters.

This is preety much nowhere documented, came across with actual experience.

Comment: yes i have also came across this recently while trying to save  large string to a custom user profile property of type string(multivalue)